# Dropbox API on iOS fails to link

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I'm unable to get my app to link to dropbox on iOS.

I create the session and ask if it's linked... if no, it opens up Dropbox to get authorization.  I say yes, and it returns to my app and sends a notification to start the upload.

But isLinked is still NO, so the file fails to upload if I try.  Any advice is appreciated.

Interestingly, the -sessionDidReceiveAuthorizationFailure: userId: delegate method is never called.

```
-(void)connectToDropbox{
    if (!dbSession) {
        dbSession    = [[DBSession alloc] initWithAppKey:@"key"
                                                   appSecret:@"secret"
                                                      root:kDBRootDropbox];

        dbSession.delegate = self;    
        [DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];
    }


    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        [self beginUpload:nil];
    } else {
        [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self.currentViewController];
    }
}

- (void)beginUpload:(NSNotification *)note {

    if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        NSError * error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"myApp"
                                              code:0
                                          userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : @"Could not link to Dropbox"}];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kErrorDidOccurNotification object:error];
        NSLog(@"File upload failed with error: %@", error);
        return;
    }

   ///do the upload if we make it here.
}


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_2){


    if ([sourceApplication isEqualToString:@"com.getdropbox.Dropbox"]) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"beginDropboxUpload" object:nil];
    }
/// more code
}
```

Comment: Show your code for your `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` delegate method that handles the `DBSession`

Comment: Ok, I added the appDelegate code.  The notification does get called.

Comment: Cross-linking with https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203508333-iOS-isLinked-always-returns-NO on the Dropbox API forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code in the app delegate isn't correct. You need something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_2) {
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
        NSString *query = url.query;
        if ([[url absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"cancel"].location == NSNotFound) { // NO_I18N
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"beginDropboxUpload" object:nil];
        } else {
            // Link cancelled
        }
    } else {
        // Something other than Dropbox
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't totally understand why this works, but thanks!

Comment: See the Dropbox docs. Calling `[[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]` is documented as being needed. This completes the login process in your app.